# How to add border on table cells, but not the whole table on html?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to add a border on table cells but I cannot figure out how to do it with rowspan.

I want a table that has 4 cells
1 big cell on the left and 3 small cells on the right of the big one.

Here's the code I used

jsfiddle[dot]net/1fv4dz5g/3/

Comment: Can't you just add a border for each td, like this : http://jsfiddle.net/1fv4dz5g/5/?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be done using CSS. Check this css sample

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="tnews-side" border="0">

<tr>
<td rowspan="3">
<table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing ="0">Row 1 Cell 1</table>
</td>
  <td>Row 1 Cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Row 2 Cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Row 2 Cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing this using CSS:

set each/all `td` a class and use css border:

```
<style>
.bigCell{border:1px solid black;}
.smallCell{border-left:1px solid black;}
</style>
...
<td class="biCell">
...
<td class="smallCell">
```

or you can use nested selection or the `:nth-child()` selector

```
<style>
table tr:nth-child(2) td
{
  border:...
}

</style>
```

you may check:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/